# calculate number of cylinders and volume in a turboprop

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I've been given the following:

- CL (lift coefficient)
- $\eta_p$ (efficiency of the propeller)
- $n_p$ (number of revolutions of the propeller)
- $n_e$ (number of revolutions of the engine)
- $\eta_g$ (efficiency of the gearbox)
- T (which is equal to R)
- Z (which is needed to calculate $\rho$)

So far I've considered that $\eta_p = \dfrac{T\cdot V}{c_p \omega_p}$ where $c_p$ is the torque of the propeller whereas $\omega_p$ is the acceleration of the propeller.

Therefore $c_p \cdot \omega_p = \dfrac{T \cdot V}{\eta_p}$ where $c_p \omega_p = \eta_g c_e \omega_e$ (torque and acceleration of the engine).

From there we know that $c_e \omega_e = \dfrac{c_p \omega_p}{\eta_g}$.

Finally $P_e = c_e \omega_e$ which is equal to $P_e = \dfrac{mep \cdot V \cdot n_{cyl}}{2\pi\alpha}$, where $P_e$ is the power of the engine, $mep$ is the mean effective pressure, $n_{cyl}$ is the number of cylinders, and

$$\alpha = \dfrac{\text{mass of air}}{\text{mass of combustible}}$$

Comment: A turboprop engine does not have cylinders; it's a turbine with a gearbox, and the gearbox drives the propeller. You're talking about a piston engine, probably a radial, perhaps with a supercharger and/or a turbocharger.

Answer (score 0):

You can find valid solutions for 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10 and 12 (or more) cylinders - 360 just happens to be divisible by all of those and so is 720... 7 cylinders is also possible

But the important point is that **nothing** in your question limits or controls the **number** of cylinders.

Comment: Why does it matter than the cylinder spacing is a whole number of degrees? There are several commercially manufactured 7-cylinder radial engines, not to mention this "little baby" … https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_R-4360_Wasp_Major

Comment: @alephzero how is 7 cylinders the correct solution to the OP's question?